# WxPython converting choice to number value TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython, wxwidgets

So I imagine this is a fairly simple question where I just don't understand the error. This is my current code:

```
        # SINGLE CHOICE INPUT
        choices = ["Auto", "Manual", "Manual (code only)"]
        chooseOneBox = wx.SingleChoiceDialog(None, "Setup / Opsætning", "Setup / Opsætning", choices)

        if chooseOneBox.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            setupChoice = choices.index[chooseOneBox.GetStringSelection()] + 1
            if setupChoice == 1:
                print(choices[setupChoice]-1)
            elif setupChoice == 2:
                print(choices[setupChoice]-1)
            print(choices[setupChoice])
```

So I have the list `choices` which contains a bunch of options which are being correctly displayed in `chooseOneBox`. When trying to do:
`setupChoice = choices.index[chooseOneBox.GetStringSelection()] + 1` I get the following error: `'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable`.

I want to convert the string from `chooseOneBox` to an integer for simplistic reasons. How do I avoid getting that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`index` is a function of the `list` that returns the first index of occurrence of an item.

Replace

```
choices.index[chooseOneBox.GetStringSelection()] + 1
```

With this

```
choices.index(chooseOneBox.GetStringSelection()) + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont see any advantage to the way that you're performing that code.
Why not this instead:

```
choices = ["Auto", "Manual", "Manual (code only)"]
chooseOneBox = wx.SingleChoiceDialog(None, "Setup / Opsætning", "Setup / Opsætning", choices)

if chooseOneBox.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
    setupChoice = choices.index(chooseOneBox.GetStringSelection())
    print(choices[setupChoice])
```

Or even more straightforwardly, using `GetSelection()` which returns the index of the item selected:

```
choices = ["Auto", "Manual", "Manual (code only)"]
chooseOneBox = wx.SingleChoiceDialog(None, "Setup / Opsætning", "Setup / Opsætning", choices)

if chooseOneBox.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
    print(choices[chooseOneBox.GetSelection()])
```